# How to distinguish between <expr> and non-<expr> mappings?

Tags: vim

I want to add a possibility of restoring mappings overwritten by my plugin. But the problem is that I cannot distinguish between the following mappings:

```
inoremap <expr> @ test
```

and

```
inoremap @ test
```

First mapping inserts the contents of the variable `test`, while second inserts text «test». Both mappings give `maparg("@", 'i')=="test"` and identical output of `inoremap i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there isn't a way to do so.  There was a [discussion](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.editors.vim/82047) about exactly this topic a few months ago and a proof of concept [patch](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.editors.vim.devel/24411) was suggested, but there was no response from Bram.  Although, it appears he did take notice as the topic is listed in Vim's [todo list](http://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/runtime/doc/todo.txt?spec=svn24100651daa9d7140d33f298c987c9d42bd919bf&r=f63ace015c6302ee9ce23c7c0f64d8134c51db95#248).